# Could not set mocks with $route in vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I'm trying to practice of test referencing [Using a Mock Router](https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vue-router.html#using-a-mock-router). Here is my code.

**NestedRoute.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
    <div>Nested Route</div>
    <div class="username">
        {{ $route.params.username }}
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from './views/Home.vue';
import NestedRoute from './views/NestedRoute.vue';

Vue.use(Router)

export const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
  { path: '/nested-route', name: 'nroute', component: NestedRoute }
];

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

**test.spec.js**

```
import NestedRoute from '@/views/NestedRoute.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import {routes} from '@/router.js'

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(VueRouter);

describe('NestedRoute', () => {
        it('renders a username from query string', () => {
            const username = 'tom';
            const $route = {
                params: { username }
            };

            const wrapper = mount(NestedRoute, {
                mocks: {
                    $route
                }
            });

            expect(wrapper.find('.username').text()).toBe(username);
        });
});
```

When I run test it, the error `[vue-test-utils]: could not overwrite property $route, this is usually caused by a plugin that has added the property as a read-only value` is occurred.

I tried to reference [a issue 'Cannot use mocks with localVue'](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/323), but I couldn't resolve my issue. How can I use a mock to use `$route`

Comment: just remove `localVue.use(VueRouter);` and everything should work. You do not have to include it if you mock it ;)

Comment: @ThomasKleßen Thank you for an answer! But when I do that, `the same error is thrown` and the test result is `Expected: "tom", Received: ""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '.../../MyComponent'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    const localVue = createLocalVue()
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      mocks: {
        $route: {
          params: {
            id: 200000
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('has $route set', () => {

  })
})
```

This is how it works for me.

The simple but very important difference is that **importing `routes` from `router.js`**. Some how the `routes` used in `Router` of `router.js` is imported at the `test.sepec.js` and it interrupt the process of `localVue` i.e, just importing routes, which is used in global router, in the test spec pollute localVue of the test.

So, remove

```
import {routes} from '@/router.js'
```

from the `test.spec.js` will resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I write test as you suggested. But still the error is occurred... The followings are what I did for it but not helpful... **1.** making an additional component for only test which is not used in `router.js`. Because I had thought "the Vue Router set the `$route` when the component is referenced as a route. **2.** I removed `localVue`

Comment: Do NOT remove localVue. This is important to not inherit a vue Instance with router attached! Also: You do NOT have to do anything with your router.js. It is not needed in this context